# FocusVisualStyle binding with custom DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, focusvisualstyle

I'm trying to change the FocusVisualStyle of a derived button that implement a CornerRadius DependencyProperty. Everything works for the button style, but I can't figure out how to send the CornerRadius value to the FocusVisualStyle.

Here my current code for the FocusVisualStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyFocusBorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyButton}}}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have also try this form of binding:

```
CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Any help would be nice :)

**EDIT** : As requested, here would be all my code:

MyButton.cs:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public int CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    // DependencyProperty as the backing store for CornerRadius
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CornerRadius",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(MyButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(3)
    );


    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }


}
```

Themes\Generic.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, ElementName=background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>




<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="MyButton"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">

                <Border x:Name="background"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>



                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="background"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="background"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT :** Considering I never found a nice solution, here's how I solved it:

```
public MyButton()
    {
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            string styleStr = "<Style xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
            "<Setter Property = \"Control.Template\"> " +
                "<Setter.Value> " +
                    "<ControlTemplate> " +
                        "<Rectangle Margin = \"-2\" " +
                                    "Stroke = \"" + Resource<SolidColorBrush>.GetColor("MaxFocusBorder") + "\" " +
                                    "StrokeThickness = \"1\" " +
                                    "StrokeDashArray = \"1 2\" " +
                                    "RadiusX = \"" + CornerRadius + "\" " +
                                    "RadiusY = \"" + CornerRadius + "\" " +
                                    "SnapsToDevicePixels = \"True\" " +
                                    "UseLayoutRounding = \"True\" /> " +
                    "</ControlTemplate> " +
               " </Setter.Value> " +
            "</Setter> " +
        "</Style>";

            FocusVisualStyle = (Style)XamlReader.Parse(styleStr);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use an **elementname**-binding?

I've simplified your code to give an illustration about my suggestion.

```
   <Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=CornerRadius}">
                        <Label Foreground="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Fill}">Template</Label>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**View**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Style="{StaticResource FocusVisualStyle}" Height="30"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Height="30" Fill="Green"/>
    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="15"/>
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see the style is applied to the label inside the stackpanel. The border within the template is getting it's cornerradius from outside (from the border inside the stackpanel named *border*).

If elementname-binding isn't the right approach for you plaese post some more code to see where your button is lying and how to get access.